# insert images and text into table cell in cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview

I'm new to this mac application development.
I have an set of few images in my path and I want to insert these images and  text under the images in an cell and later take the print of this. I want 3 rows and 5 columns cells. How can i do this??

Answer (score 0):

1) Create `NSViewController` `TableViewCell.h`

2) Create in `TableViewCell.h` some procedures like

`-(void)setText:(NSString *)text image:(NSImage *)image`

3) In Main class `#import "TableViewCell.h"`

4) In Main class in `-(NSView *)tableView:viewForTableColumn:row:` write:

```
NSImage *img = //some image
TableViewCell *cell = [[TableViewCell alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"TableViewCell"];
cell.view.init;
[cell setText:@"some text" image:img];
return cell;
```

Hope this will help =)

**EDIT:**

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView {
    return 3;
}
```